# Don't add output result to map in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

Whenever I execute some GIS operation the output is automatically added to the map. Is there any option in ArcMap to turn off this setting?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit Geoprocessing options. You can find this at top menu of ArcMap window. Uncheck the "Add the result of geoprocessing to the display"